# How to use query result text as another query's where condition at once?

Tags: mysql, sql

In those 2 tables

```
Table A [id, items]
        [1, "a,b,c"]

Table B [id , contents]
        ["a", apple]
        ["b", banana]
```

I want to get result as [apple, banana] at once like query

```sql
select contents from B where B.id in ("a","b","c")
```

or like

```
select contents from B where B.id in (select A.items from A where id = 1)
```

Comment: Normalize your schema. See ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) (Spoiler: Yes, it is.).

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two tables with the [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```sql
SELECT contents
FROM   b
JOIN   a ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.items) > 0
WHERE  a.id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response.